# Guide won't automatically generate an m file

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, file-rename

I am working in matlab gui GUIDE and I am trying to rename a file. I open the fig file in GUIDE and save it as the new file name but a new .m file is NOT created. Consequently I cannot run the gui or edit the file. I have seen a lot of posts about this and many people say "Save As" should just work which is strange because it was working for me yesterday too. Does anyone know the reason why sometimes GUIDE does not automatically generate an m file?

Comment: One more thing. I have another file with corresponding m and fig filenames. If I edit the fig file (change callback names etc.) it does not update the m file anymore.

Comment: It didn't happen to me, and I cannot reproduce this behavior. Are you sure that closing and re-opening MATLAB won't "fix" this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two files MUST have the same name. See the documentation here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/files-generated-by-guide.html

Further more, I can't find specific examples in the documentation, but there seems to be a common issue with Callbacks and UI property names getting a little messed up. The best bet is of course is to not touch the file names (or create the GUI programmatically) but now that the damage is done, I would reccommend:

- Making sure both files have the same name
- Checking all button callbacks to make sure they point to the right file
- Checking the tag of all your graphics objects to make sure they are the sames

Double check in your GUIDE options that it is still set to generate an mfile ( Tools > Gui options > Create m file )

Best of luck, GUIDE can be good, but is very far from perfect. (especially in times like now)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have made sure that the name of the fig and .m file is the same. Still when I change a callback in the fig file, it does not edit the m file. I have tried restarting matlab and even using different files but none of my GUIs are updating. And with all of them, when I save them as a new name in GUIDE no m file is created. I am so confused! I need to do this as I am creating a new GUI based on an old one.

Comment: It's a pain in the butt, and the reason I don't use GUIDE, but I myself have had trouble like copying the file and then changing things. I don't have MATLAB on this computer, but it might be worthwhile checking some of the GUIDE options in the menu bar at the top to see if you can set the file its connected to or see if thats the issue. If your GUI isn't too crazy, just starting over could save you some headaches. In the long run, learn to make them programmatically :) lots of benefits such as having only one file, more intuitive scoping, and code reuse

Comment: You're a genius. There was a button under Tools > Gui options > Create m file which had been unticked. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad that worked for you, I added your solution to my answer, I'd appreciate it if you did accept my answer